# Gap between table and div

Tags: html, css-tables

I have 3 floated divs inside a td. Divs touch eachother with no gap just fine but there is a gap around either the table or td (looks like a 1px border). I have tried:

```
margin:0
padding:0
border: 0 
cellspacing: 0 
cellpadding: 0
border-collapse:collapse
```

Heres my jfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tcHKB/5/
I changed it to try and highlight the problem. You can't see the top gap but you can see the white gap on the right of the box that says "left" and on the left of the box that says "right"

Comment: please post [sscce](http://sscce.org/) so that we can see what we are dealing with.

Comment: ... best would be jsfiddle of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width` property of the DIV doesn't match the cell's width.

Relevant CSS:

```
.MCmiddle{
    width: 732px;
}
#main_content_box{
   width: 730px;
}
```

Either change the width of `#main_content_box` to `732px`, *or* change the width of `.MCmiddle` to `730px`.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tcHKB/7/**

Comment: Sorry you were looking at the wrong gap. Updated jsfiddle to make it a little easier to see. Its the 1px gap between the red and the red on the left and the red and the light blue on the right. http://jsfiddle.net/tcHKB/5/

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple. Thank you!